# Element not found when using webdriver with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, element

got a problem with my code and I need your help. What I'm trying to do is the following:

1- access a website;

2- fill the registration form: `name`, `email`, `password`, etc.

Step 1 works; after clicking the sign up button, the form will pop up in a new tab.

Step 2; when trying to find the elements, by, `id` or `name`, I get the error `"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"`

My code is the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign Up').click()

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("signup_title").send_keys(signup_tile)
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_name").send_keys(signup_name)
```

Attached you can find the html. Thank you in advance, much appreciated your help.
**Note**

In console I tried to find the element searching the `id` using
`$x("//*[@id='signup_title']") and it was found: [input#signup_title.sc-AxirZ.kzqQJb.invalid]`. Also the element is loaded.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPq9K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```python
driver.find_element_by_xpath("<XPath>")
```

It seems to work better. To get the XPath of an element, find the element in the inspector, right-click it then Copy -> Copy XPath. If that doesn't work, select Copy Full XPath instead

Comment: Got the same error but now for the XPath: ElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/main/div/form/div[1]/input"}

Comment: Can the error be related to the fact that after clicking the ''sign up'' button, the form will open in another tab? Then how can I do the search of the elements in the new tab?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the second tab; because the form opens in another tab, the window must be switched in the code.
I used the following:
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles['Nr']), Nr being the index for the tab- if there are 2, the main one, and the second one-in my case with the form, the index will pe 1-counting starts from zero.